# React Redux Immutable Deeply Nested Array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this structure

Server response from the API

[server response json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ttV.png)

Each of this topics must be in a separate response

[my drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKEXJ.jpg)

1. topics ( object )

   - matches ( array )

     - comments ( array )

So basically the array has 3 levels

I want to add a new subticket in a specific ticket in a specific

This is the state graph

[redux graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKiLI.png)

this works but obviously mutable

```
state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index].subtickets = state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index].subtickets.concat(action.subticket);
return {...state};
```

this also works and is immutable but it appends to the second layer ( tickets )

```
  return {
    ...state
    ,[topic_id]:{
      ...state[topic_id]
      ,tickets:[
        ...state[topic_id].tickets
        ,action.subticket
      ]
    }
  }  ;
```

considering this , this should work, but it does not

```
  return {
    ...state
    ,[topic_id]:{
      ...state[topic_id]
      ,tickets:[
        ...state[topic_id].tickets
        ,[topic_id]:[
    ...state[topic_id].tickets[topic_id],
    subtickets:[
        ...state[topic_id].tickets[topic_id].subtickets,
        action.subticket
        ]
      ]
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am trying for 2 days I have no idea what is wrong with the last statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below:

```
{
  ...state,
  [topic_id]: {
      ...state[topic_id],
      tickets: [
        ...state[topic_id].tickets.slice(0, ticket_index),

        state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index] = {
            ...state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index],
            subticket: [
                ...state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index].subticket,
                {id: "st15"} // new subticket
            ] 
        },

        ...state[topic_id].tickets.slice(ticket_index + 1)
      ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: yes, this was it

still dont understand why

[
        ...state[topic_id].tickets.slice(0, ticket_index),

        state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index] = {
            ...state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index],
            subticket: [
                ...state[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index].subticket,
                {id: "st15"} // new subticket
            ] 
        },

instead of

        ...state[topic_id].tickets
        ,[topic_id]:[
    ...state[topic_id].tickets[topic_id],
    subtickets:[
        {{...}}
        ]
      ]

but it works so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

update: this works

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';

{...}

let newState = cloneDeep(state);

newState[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index].subtickets = newState[topic_id].tickets[ticket_index].subtickets.concat(action.subticket);

return newState;
```

from what I understand, cloneDeep is not very performant

still, a answer for what is wrong with the 3rd piece of code from the original comment would be appreciated